# Connect points on a scatterplot to the two other most similar points given a correlation matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I have clustered a few points and have computed the mean of each cluster as a landmark point for that cluster. I have then computed a correlation matrix among all landmark points to see which are most similar. Now I'd like to *connect* each landmark points to its two most similar neighbors. Since these landmark points do not have X,Y coordinates on the clustering map, I am using the centroid points for each cluster as starting point to connect landmarks.

My `assignments` data.frame looks something like this:

```
> head(assignments)
                  Transcripts Genes Timepoint Run Cluster       V1          V2              Cell    meanX      meanY
8A_0_AATCTGCACCAA      143327 10542     Day 0  8A       6 113.8933  -2.1280855 8A_0_AATCTGCACCAA 124.3976  -8.682189
8A_0_CATGTCCTATCT      117322 10334     Day 0  8A       6 110.0499  -2.1553971 8A_0_CATGTCCTATCT 124.3976  -8.682189
8A_0_ATGCTCAATTGG      102764  9974     Day 0  8A       6 104.7227  -0.8397611 8A_0_ATGCTCAATTGG 124.3976  -8.682189
8A_0_CTACGGGAGAGT       92832  9651     Day 0  8A       6 101.3370  -5.0928108 8A_0_CTACGGGAGAGT 124.3976  -8.682189
8A_0_GTAGGGCGCGCT       90264  8807     Day 0  8A       6 113.3947 -18.9441484 8A_0_GTAGGGCGCGCT 124.3976  -8.682189
8A_0_ACGAGCTAACGG       83663  9148     Day 0  8A       7 114.6545 -31.6095622 8A_0_ACGAGCTAACGG 113.3952 -38.072025
```

.. and is used to generate the plot below:

```
ggplot(assignments, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point(aes(colour=Cluster)) + geom_text(aes(meanX, meanY, label=Cluster), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, color='black', size=10)
```

[image]

Now given the following landmark correlation matrix (shown below), I'd like to connect each centroid point to it's nearest/most correlated two others.

```
> correlations
           1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10
1  1.0000000 0.8269796 0.7542429 0.8443087 0.5627945 0.7106869 0.6511076 0.7880531 0.7279651 0.7842836
2  0.8269796 1.0000000 0.9491927 0.9723831 0.6921389 0.9001103 0.8452948 0.9581868 0.9001655 0.9408375
3  0.7542429 0.9491927 1.0000000 0.9376269 0.7786622 0.8843569 0.8662250 0.9243512 0.9026685 0.9570069
4  0.8443087 0.9723831 0.9376269 1.0000000 0.6919623 0.9091975 0.8542862 0.9568544 0.9019741 0.9461385
5  0.5627945 0.6921389 0.7786622 0.6919623 1.0000000 0.7064235 0.7538936 0.6941766 0.7517064 0.7844258
6  0.7106869 0.9001103 0.8843569 0.9091975 0.7064235 1.0000000 0.9341175 0.9404398 0.8969552 0.8830658
7  0.6511076 0.8452948 0.8662250 0.8542862 0.7538936 0.9341175 1.0000000 0.8822696 0.9116052 0.8958741
8  0.7880531 0.9581868 0.9243512 0.9568544 0.6941766 0.9404398 0.8822696 1.0000000 0.9316483 0.9219810
9  0.7279651 0.9001655 0.9026685 0.9019741 0.7517064 0.8969552 0.9116052 0.9316483 1.0000000 0.9402076
10 0.7842836 0.9408375 0.9570069 0.9461385 0.7844258 0.8830658 0.8958741 0.9219810 0.9402076 1.0000000
```

The resulting plot is anticipated to look similar to the plot above but with an over lay of a sort of network, where centroids are connect to 2 most similar neighbors/centroids. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT1**:

I should mention that the landmark cells which are used to produce the correlation matrix is simply an average of the underlying data for cells within the designated cluster:

```
# compute `landmark cell` for each cluster
data = cbind(assignments, t(dge[,assignments$Cell]))
cluster.gene.avg.list = list()
for(n in unique(data$Cluster)) {temp.cluster = subset(data, Cluster==n)[,11:ncol(data)]; cluster.gene.avg.list[[n]] = rowMeans(t(temp.cluster))}
landmark = do.call(cbind, cluster.gene.avg.list)
```

.. Where `dge` are gene expression values and a matrix with dimensions of 16015 by 2449:

```
> head(dge[,1:5])
              8A_3_GACACGTAGGCC 8A_3_TTACAAATGTCA 8A_3_GCTCAAATCTTC 8A_7_CCGCCCCGACTT 8A_0_AATCTGCACCAA
0610005C13RIK        0.00000000        0.00000000        0.09081976        0.00000000         0.0000000
0610007P14RIK        0.34322315        0.39803339        0.72224870        0.80916196         0.3551089
0610009B22RIK        0.07548816        0.25172063        0.17625931        0.18493077         0.4317327
0610009L18RIK        0.00000000        0.17259527        0.09081976        0.00000000         0.0000000
0610009O20RIK        0.00000000        0.08887713        0.09081976        0.09542651         0.0000000
0610010B08RIK        0.56896378        0.91807267        0.83163550        0.86439381         0.7635860
```

**EDIT2**

Thanks to /u/sandipan for the help!

```
# correlation between each landmark
correlations = cor(landmark, method="spearman") # correlation methods: pearson, spearman or kendall
dist.correlations = dist(1-cor(landmark, method="spearman"))
diag(correlations) = 0 

# find the 2 nearest neighbors by highest correlation
nnbrs <- as.data.frame(t(apply(correlations, 1, function(x) {y <- sort(x, index.return=TRUE, decreasing=TRUE); c(y$ix[1],y$x[1],y$ix[2],y$x[2])})),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(nnbrs) <- c('id1', 'dist1', 'id2', 'dist2')
nnbrs$id <- seq(1,length(names(landmark)))
nnbrs1 <- nnbrs[c('id', 'id1', 'dist1')]
nnbrs2 <- nnbrs[c('id', 'id2', 'dist2')]
names(nnbrs2) <- c('id', 'id1', 'dist1')
nnbrs <- rbind(nnbrs1, nnbrs2)

# create data.frame of center coordinates for each cluster
centers = data.frame(unique(cbind(assignments$Cluster,assignments$meanX, assignments$meanY)))
names(centers) = c("Cluster", "X", "Y")
centers = centers[order(centers$Cluster),]

# create data.frame of line segements based on 2 nearest correlations
segments = t(apply(nnbrs, 1, function(x) c(centers[as.integer(x[1]), 2:3], centers[as.integer(x[2]), 2:3], as.numeric(x[3]))))
segments = data.frame(t(do.call(cbind, segments)))
names(segments) <- c('x', 'y', 'xend', 'yend', 'corr')
segments = data.frame(sapply(segments, as.numeric))
segments$corr <- as.factor(segments$corr)
plot + geom_segment(data=segments, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend, col=corr), lwd=1.2) + guides(col=FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]

Now time to figure out how to keep the cluster colors and create a continuous color scale for the correlation based segments!

Comment: Shouldn't you also be posting the data on the centroids?

Comment: The centroids are simply mean X and Y values of all cells within a specific cluster. This is how I annotate the cluster number on the plot. Specifically, this is done by `assignments %>% group_by(Cluster) %>% mutate(meanX=mean(V1), meanY=mean(V2))` and this is how we get the `meanX` and `meanY` centroid coordinates on the plot. I'll update my post to show how I defined these landmark cells (avg of all cells in cluster).

Comment: I think he's just asking for the data to help facilitate coding and testing for us. It's easy enough to give to us. Like so: `centroidV1<-by(assignments$V1, assignments$Cluster, mean)`

Comment: I will update the post to share my original data and full scripts.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest making a **minimal** reproducible example - maybe 2 or 3 clusters, 5 to 10 points per cluster. I think you will find a solution much easier to work out (and people here much more eager to help). Bonus points if you share a little function that generates examples of a given size - that way solutions are easy to benchmark to see how they scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (with synthetically generated data with 8 clusters and randomly generated correlation matrix):

```
head(assignments)
          V1       V2 Cluster     meanX    meanY
1  -96.93875 89.73655       8 -99.24848 50.61038
2  -96.86518 63.81925       8 -99.24848 50.61038
3  -76.63706 59.05426       8 -99.24848 50.61038
4 -105.90429 60.40880       8 -99.24848 50.61038
5 -100.39240 54.27822       8 -99.24848 50.61038
6  -99.53031 39.01734       8 -99.24848 50.61038

#res <- kmeans(assignments, 8) # 8 clusters
#centers <- res$centers # for kmeans

centers <- centers[,2:3] # in you case

correlations # this will be a 10x10 matrix in your case
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]      [,7]      [,8]
[1,] 0.28708827 0.12476841 0.24545908 0.2588388 0.2074115 0.75373879 0.8104132 0.5754160
[2,] 0.73768137 0.47982080 0.67638982 0.7976242 0.9919874 0.68068729 0.9534392 0.2404903
[3,] 0.94252193 0.03406601 0.87475370 0.4167443 0.9181345 0.75985783 0.6763228 0.9912269
[4,] 0.09300806 0.26816248 0.77741727 0.3892989 0.8545009 0.79482925 0.5123970 0.3311057
[5,] 0.69044589 0.04903995 0.14823010 0.9018917 0.9461897 0.04739289 0.6008395 0.2522856
[6,] 0.07651553 0.36061880 0.92448094 0.2414908 0.9768005 0.50474048 0.1748254 0.9701859
[7,] 0.07449400 0.30025228 0.05877126 0.1055387 0.6143566 0.87633754 0.8646951 0.1123956
[8,] 0.58755791 0.44420559 0.17486185 0.3668967 0.7989782 0.21354636 0.3137961 0.1086797

p <- ggplot(assignments, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point(aes(colour=Cluster)) + geom_text(aes(meanX, meanY, label=Cluster), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, color='black', size=10)

# compute the endpoints of the segments to draw with the 2 NNs for each cluster
library(reshape2)
nnbrs <- as.data.frame(t(apply(correlations, 1, function(x) sort(x, index.return=TRUE)$ix[1:2])),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
nnbrs$id <- 1:8 # 8 clusters
nnbrs <- melt(nnbrs, id='id')
segments <- as.data.frame(t(apply(nnbrs, 1, function(x) cbind(centers[as.integer(x[1]),],centers[as.integer(x[3]),]))))
names(segments) <- c('x', 'y', 'xend', 'yend')

p + geom_segment(data=segments, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend))
```

[image]

If you want segments colored w.r.t. correlation value, try this (with a different set of randomly generated points):

```
p <- ggplot(assignments, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point(aes(colour=Cluster)) + geom_text(aes(meanX, meanY, label=Cluster), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, color='black', size=10)
nnbrs <- as.data.frame(t(apply(correlations, 1, function(x) {y <- sort(x, index.return=TRUE); c(y$ix[1],y$x[1],y$ix[2],y$x[2])})),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(nnbrs) <- c('id1', 'dist1', 'id2', 'dist2')
nnbrs$id <- 1:8
nnbrs1 <- nnbrs[c('id', 'id1', 'dist1')]
nnbrs2 <- nnbrs[c('id', 'id2', 'dist2')]
names(nnbrs2) <- c('id', 'id1', 'dist1')
nnbrs <- rbind(nnbrs1, nnbrs2)
segments <- as.data.frame(t(apply(nnbrs, 1, function(x) c(centers[as.integer(x[1]),],centers[as.integer(x[2]),],as.numeric(x[3])))))
names(segments) <- c('x', 'y', 'xend', 'yend', 'corr')
segments$corr <- as.factor(segments$corr)
p + geom_segment(data=segments, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend, col=corr),lwd=1.2) +  guides(col=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks promising! Is there any way to color or weigh the line segments based on the corresponding correlations?

Comment: Hmm. What is `res` in your example? Also `nnbrs` in my case does not seem to make sense to me. I'll add an update to the OP.

Comment: res is the result object from kmeans

Comment: I've never run kmeans. Clustering was actually preformed using the DBSCAN method. I have a created a new data.frame with center coordinates for each cluster named `centers`. Will post in edit.

Comment: Does not matter what clustering method you use, the result is going to be a grouping of the points into the clusters and the centroids of them. Just use the corresponding variables / methods to extract the cluster numbers and the centers from your result object.

Comment: I agree I'm just struggling to run the `segments` definition given my `centers` data.frame. `segments <- as.data.frame(t(apply(nnbrs, 1, function(x) c(centers[as.integer(x[1]),],centers[as.integer(x[2]),],as.numeric(x[3])))))` does not seem to work properly.

Comment: your centers dataframe has 3 columns unlike kmeans centers that has 2 columns. Use this modified code: 

segments <- as.data.frame(t(apply(nnbrs, 1, function(x) c(centers[as.integer(x[1]),2:3],centers[as.integer(x[2]),2:3],
as.n‌​umeric(x[3]))))), 

it should work.

Comment: The code is returning a data.frame of lists? I've posted another edit.

Comment: I've tried both, the code in the comment above and in the respond to this thread, but unfortunately they are not returning a 5 column data.frame. Weird.

Comment: segments should be a 20x5 data frame in your case, what are the dimesions of segments? also what's the class of center? is it a data frame? nnbrs looks okay.

Comment: centers is a data.frame. I manipulated `segments` by `t(apply(nnbrs, 1, function(x) c(centers[as.integer(x[1]), 2:3], centers[as.integer(x[2]), 2:3], as.numeric(x[3]))))` then `data.frame(t(do.call(cbind, segments)))` to get a 20 x 5 data.frame but when I run `segments$corr <- as.factor(segments$corr)` it returns `Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?`. Its seems like even though the class of `segments` is data.frame, the columns are still lists. Posting edit now.

Comment: yes, sort is here:

nnbrs <- as.data.frame(t(apply(correlations, 1, function(x) {y <- sort(x, index.return=TRUE); c(y$ix[1],y$x[1],y$ix[2],y$x[2])})),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: may be u can try cbind() instead of c() to concatenate 5 columns, but c() should also work, there is something silly happening that we are not able to figure out.

Comment: what's class(segments$corr)? what's class(segments)?

Comment: `segments$corr` is of class `list`. `segments` is of class `data.frame`.

Comment: what's str(segments)?

Comment: try the hack segments$corr <- as.factor(unlist(segments$corr))

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you for your help! Now I'm just trying to get a continuous scale for correlation. Ill post the solution in the OP.

Comment: do you know of a way to keep cluster cluster while adding a continuous scale for the line segments?